# Why is this video not being embedded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, embedded-video

Here's my application.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.oembed').embedly({maxWidth:600,'method':'replace'});
});
```

Here's my `show` view:

```
<div id="video_div"><%= link_to 'video', @video.video_url, :class => 'oembed' %></div>
```

The result is simply the link to the youtube video with the text "video". The video is not being embedded.

I input the link in my `new` view and save `@video.video_url` to the db.

I successfully include these files:

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.embedly.js?1299981574" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js?1299978321" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1299978356" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1300064036" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reordering the includes so that embedly is included after jquery. If you look at the javascript console in inspector/firebug you'll probably see that embedly can't find the jQuery variable.